# Обновление репозитория git без ввода паролей

Tags: linux, git, git-remote, git-pull

Есть корпоративный аккаунт "А" с приватными репозиториями на github.com;
есть аккаунт "B" - мой обычный аккаунт, который имеет административный доступ к репозиториям аккаунта "А".

При обновлении репозитория на сервере через консоль командой `git pull` система каждый раз запрашивает пароль. Ввожу пароль аккаунта "В" и команда успешно выполняетя.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при вводе команды из консоли, система не запрашивала пароль? Это должно позволить выполнять обновление репозитория из php.

Что для этого нужно, размещать какой-то специальный ключ на сервере?

Comment: remote для репозитория указан как https или как ssh?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Запустите в консоли команду `git remote -v` и посмотрите, через какой протокол у вас осуществляется доступ к репозиторию.

Если это https, то будет примерно следующий путь:

```
https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

Для ssh будет такой:

```
git@github.com:USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

#### https

> Требуется Git версии не ниже 1.7.10

В этом случае вам всегда требуется указывать пароль при общении с сервером. Git можно попросить [сохранять](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/gitcredentials.html) на некоторое время (по умолчанию на 15 минут) введённые данные командой:

```
> git config --global credential.helper cache
```

При желании можно изменить стандартное время запоминания командой

```
> git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=3600"
```

(время указывается в секундах)

Вы можете также указать git хранить ваши данные постоянно:

```
> git config credential.helper store
```

При этом ваши данные будут храниться в открытом виде в файле .git-credentials.

Обнулить настройки этой возможности можно командой:

```
> git config --unset credential.helper
```

При желании можно подобное поведение для всех репозиториев, для этого нужно передать дополнительный ключ `--global`.

В зависимости от этой настройки, информация с вашими данными будет расположена либо в каталоге проекта, либо в `$HOME`

> Для версий Git, ниже 1.7.10

Вы можете указать информацию для авторизации в url, по которому осуществляете доступ к репозиторию, для этого его нужно преобразовать так:

```
https://username:password@github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

Измените текущий url в remote на указанный (как это сделать, описано ниже в ответе) и авторизация не будет запрашиваться.

Помните, что и в этом случае ваши данные будут храниться в открытом виде.

> Для Git версии не ниже 0.99

Существует возможность настроить [netrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214)

#### SSH

Про работу с запароленным ключём SSH знаю лишь то, что можно настроить [ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/), который аналогично позволит не вводить каждый раз пароль от ключа ssh.

Для начала [создайте](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) ssh-ключ с помощью команды:

```
> ssh-keygen
```

Она попросит ввести имя файла (во многих случаях можно оставить имя по умолчанию) и пароль. Пароль при желании можно оставить пустым, для этого просто дважды нажмите Enter при запросе пароля ([обычно рекомендуется устанавливать пароль](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/)).

По умолчанию пара ключей появляется в каталоге `~/.ssh/`. Вам нужно скопировать содержимое файла `id_rsa.pub` (если вы не задавали другое при создании ключа) и сохранить его в своём профиле на GitHub (Settings -> SSH Keys -> Add SSH key).

После этого можно перейти к настройке `ssh-agent`:

Выполните команду:

```
> echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
```

Если `ssh-agent` запущен, то должен вернуться его номер процесса. В этом случае можно пропустить следующий пункт и перейти к команде `ssh-add`.
Если вернулась пустая строка, необходимо запустить `ssh-agent` перед продолжением.

Запускаем `ssh-agent` в фоне:

```
> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
# Agent pid 59566
```

Теперь осталось добавить сгенерированный ключ в `ssh-agent`:

```
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

Если вы настроите доступ по ssh к своему репозиторию с использованием ключа, то работу, вероятно, можно будет производить и из программ.

---

Для уже созданного репозитория [можно изменить способ доступа](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/), используя команду

```
> git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

где `<new-url>` задаёт путь, в котором используется нужный протокол

Comment: команда `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` запустит новый процесс `ssh-agent`-а, что, скорее всего, излишне: в популярных дистрибутивах `ssh-agent` обычно уже запущен, в чём можно убедиться, например, из наличия переменной окружения `SSH_AGENT_PID`: если команда `echo $SSH_AGENT_PID` возвращает не пустую строку, а номер (процесса `ssh-agent`), то команду `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` выполнять не нужно, а следует переходить ко второй (`ssh-add`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо, добавлю это в ответ

Comment: Альтернативные варианты - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/1159507

Comment: @anber, спасибо, добавил выдержку из того обсуждения в ответ

Comment: @Timofey Bondarev вы пишите "Теперь осталось добавить сгенерированный ключ в ssh-agent" вот я не понимаю где этот ключ генерируется? На хостинге [http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-SSH-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0] или на самом github.com как-то?

Comment: @maler1988 обновил ответ. Кратко: ключ нужно создать с помощью `ssh-keygen`. Он должен храниться на компьютере, которому требуется авторизация на GitHub. Публичный ключ нужно добавить в настройках GitHub

Comment: Всем спасибо! Всё получилось!