# Git не подхватывает config любого уровня. Или "Поле user.name бесполезно?"

Tags: linux, git, git-push, git-config

Привет всем!

Такая проблема: `Git` почему-то **не подхватывает настройки**, когда я пытаюсь запушить что-либо. То есть он **постоянно просит ввести `Username` и `Password`**, хотя, по идее, он **должен просить только `Password`**

Настройки делал глобальные. То есть:

```
git config --global user.name 'SomeName'
git config --global user.email some@email.com
```

Но также пытался создать и **локальный конфиг**, и **системный конфиг**... **Ни один не подхватывается**.

Пытаюсь подключиться к `GitHub`, использую `Linux`.

Читал конфиги, думал, может что-то не так пишется, но нет. **Всё в конфигах прописано корректно**. Смущает разве что только табуляция вместо пробелов. Но не я устанавливаю правила форматирования.

Интересно то, что с `GitLab` всё отлично работает. Ну у них работает всё, ибо они сразу дают твой логин в `url`, а вот с `GitHub` это решается заменой `origin` с

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

на

```
https://username@github.com/username/repo.git
```

Но я не пойму, для чего тогда нужны настройки, если они не подхватываются? Может, они работают как-то иначе/предназначены для чего-то другого?

Comment: `user.name` относится к указанию авторства коммитов, а не к авторизации

Comment: Возможно вас заинтересует возможность кешировать данные авторизации на время: `git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'`

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо, заинтересует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Смысл `user.name` и `user.email`

Настройки `user.name` и `user.email` используются для того, чтобы сохранять в коммитах информацию об авторстве. Например, так можно посмотреть данные последнего коммита:

```
git cat-file commit HEAD
```

Пример вывода, обратите внимание на третью и четвертую строки:

```
tree 2159e904426c047e790d559c7cc62dd3d4b5174e
parent 60b9a77a21a464d71171e483d1bc834ea6fde209
author Name Surname <name@mail.td> 1461622007 +0200
committer Name Surname <name@mail.td> 1461622007 +0200
```

Смысл такой:

- `author` – автор изменений в коде
- `committer` – тот, кто закоммитил эти изменения в git.

Обычно они совпадают, в редких случаях отличаются.

## Что делать с авторизацией

Способ авторизации зависит от того, что вы используете для обмена данных с удаленным репозиторием:

- Протокол HTTPS (с адресом вида `https://github.com/username/repo-name.git`)
- Протокол SSH (с адресом вида `git@github.com:username/repo-name.git`)
- Собственный протокол Git. Используется редко, здесь рассматривать не будем.

([Подробнее о протоколах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427817/181472))

В первом случае вам всегда нужно вводить логин и пароль. Вот 
[vp_arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth) подсказывает в комментарии, что можно настроить их кеширование, чтобы вводить приходилось пореже:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'
```

Вместо этого рекомендую вам использовать протокол SSH, где для авторизации используются ключи и поэтому не нужно каждый раз вводить логин и пароль. Авторизацию по SSH нужно однократно [настроить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420044/181472).

Comment: Не хочу париться с ssh, спасибо за инфу

Comment: @KitScribe зря, там негде париться, всё предельно просто.