# При попытке создать коммит ошибка "Please tell me who you are"

Tags: git

в Win 10 пишу команды из консоли Git-Bash в закладках Open Server [image: 1 scrin]

после команды: git commit -m "first commit"
[image: 2 scrin после команды: git commit -m"first commit"]

[image: 3 scrin][image: 4 scrin]

Comment: Пожалуйста, выкладывайте не скриншоты а текст (прямо копируйте из консоли). Поисковики пока что не умеют индексировать текст на картинках и в ближайшее время не научатся.

Answer (score 3):

`user.name` и `user.email` – это имя и электронная почта автора кода.

Эти настройки [нужны для того, чтобы подписывать коммиты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658657/181472). Без них коммит создать нельзя.

Заметьте, что перед второй строкой нет `$`. Похоже, вы их как-то копировали вместе, либо там что-то не так с кавычками. В результате получается ошибка синтаксиса команды `git config`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполните команды ещё раз, по одной. В качестве `user.name` обычно используют собственное имя.

```
git config --global user.email 'username@mail.ru'
git config --global user.name 'Name Surname'
```

Когда вы выполните эту конфигурацию, станет можно создавать коммиты.

Comment: А в остальном всё правильно делаете, не хватает только первоначальной настройки.

Comment: что-то не так всё ровно( user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 MINGW32 /d/sites/mm.loc (master)
$ git config --global user.email "justfalk@mail.ru"                                                                                                                                             $ git config --global user.name "MailaGoogle"
usage: git config [<options>]
и выдаёт все тоже самое после

Comment: @Fin, надо, наверное, научиться работать в shell.

Comment: @Fin вы же сами не вводите с клавиатуры `$`? После каждой команды жмете Enter?

Comment: @Fin проверил — у меня срабатывают ваши команды. Прямо скопировал в консоль и выполнил.

Comment: C консоли в каждой строчке name и email ввожу 2 раза $ и нажимаю Enter, но проблема, как мне кажется, вообще сейчас в авторизации. В win10 git уже был установлен на Open Server, поэтому сразу не было возможности, следуя рекомендациям указать в настройках имя и почту. И теперь каждый раз при изменении файлов и попыткам сделать commit в консоли запрашивается имя и почта. Но и после этого фиксации не происходит. Если, к примеру, в ветке master или другой были сделаны изменения- то их нет. Везде все одинаково. Однако выгрузка и загрузка на github происходит нормально. Как решить?