# Как пройти проверку name и hostname в git?

Tags: git, github

При каждом коммите гит выдает вот такое сообщение. И хотя данные репозиторий приходят мне кажется что тут что-то не так. Гит сам предлагает "подавлять" если я правильно понял, это сообщение используя `git config --global --edit` или 
`git commit --amend --reset-author` но меня это настораживает. Стоит ли воспользоваться этим предложением или нет? И в чем все таки его смысл в контексте авторизации в целом?

```
$ git commit -m "add servlet for addition proposes"
[master f38f94b] add servlet for addition proposes
 Committer: My Mac <MyMac@MacBook-Pro-My.local>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
your configuration file:

    git config --global --edit

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не выполнили [начальную конфигурацию git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658657/181472) — не ввели ваше имя и почту.
Git не видит их и пытается вместо них подставить хоть что-то.

Выполните следующие команды (подставьте ваше имя и почту):

```
git config --global user.name Name Surname
git config --global user.email your.email@mailserver.tld
```

---

Вероятно, вы либо сменили рабочую машину, либо учетную запись, либо как-то удалили конфиг.
Сейчас в коммитах используется имя и почта `My Mac <MyMac@MacBook-Pro-My.local>`. Смотрите, как Гитхаб показывает ваши коммиты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ♦ да вы правы действительно сменил машину. Вот только где посмотреть как Гитхаб показывает мои коммиты я не понял(

Comment: @Pavel откройте репозиторий, нажмите ссылку "N commits". https://github.com/triodjangopiter/Automobile-Magazine/commits/master

Comment: @Pavel но вообще он будет показывать точно то же, что и команда `git log` в консоли.

Comment: ♦  я все понял спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что гит добавляет автора и почту при создании комита. Если они не заданы, гит автоматически строит их на основе имени пользователя и имени компьютера. Так же предлагает их проверить и изменить при необходимости. К авторизации это не имеет никакого отношения