# Проблема с commit and push

Tags: git, github

```
15:06   VcsException
            Couldn't set user.name and user.email: error: could not lock config file Z://.gitconfig: Permission denied
            during executing git -c core.quotepath=false config --global user.name amirzayev
```

Z:// - это обшедоступный диск на работе, непойму почему Git  хочет попасть туда, где это изменить и на что ?

Comment: Какая ОС используется? Проверь владельца файла .gitconfig.

Comment: @AresGod да в любом случае хранить свой конфиг на шаре не стоит. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а если им нужно что-бы, коммиты были от 1 человека?) Хотя это ломает представление о Git:)

Comment: @ Nick Volynkin дело в том, что конфиг не там. Я не понимаю, почему android studio пытается коммитить туда и ищет конфиг там. + к этому, когда я открываю Git bush, сперва подключается к Z:

Comment: @AresGod я пока не понимаю даже, в какой ситуации гит может искать конфиги на диске Z.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, или кто-то конфиг вручную поправил в gitbush, или возможно, в Git GUI что-то натворили.

Answer (score 4):

Какая-то программа с помощью команды `git -c core.quotepath=false config --global user.name amirzayev` пытается сконфигурировать git.
Вероятно, по адресу `Z://.gitconfig` нет файла конфигурации. Это очень логично — почему бы вдруг вашей конфигурации быть на общедоступном диске?

Настройки `user.name` и `user.email` [нужны для того, чтобы подписывать коммиты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658657/181472) вашим именем и электронной почтой. Без них нельзя создать коммит, то есть не получится полноценно работать с Git.

Настройте Git самостоятельно, есть шанс что тогда глупая программа не будет делать это за вас. Только подставьте свой настоящий адрес электронной почты:

```
git config --global user.name Arzu Mirzayev
git config --global user.email "amirzayev@mycompany.tld"
```

Comment: @user.name и user.email добавил я. Все равно ошибка та же

Comment: @ArzuMirzayev а где у вас эта ошибка возникает?

Comment: @ArzuMirzayev и в ответ на какие ваши действия?

Comment: commit and push в android studio

Comment: @ArzuMirzayev похоже, студия командует гитом через командную оболочку, которая считает, что  ваша домашняя директория это Z. Покопайте в настройках студии.