SSH ключ на github
Как создать свой SSH ключ GitHub быстро и удобно для разового использования?

Точно так же, как и любой другой SSH-ключ не GitHub

@andreymal, как создать любой другой ключ?

https://github.com/settings/tokens - возможно вы ищите это? Где генерировать access токены?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420044/264178
